"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'puttit')"
so. i'm doing a web course's capstone project. for some reason whenever i submit my form it throws this at me (all ive edited is changing where it says my real actual name to 'siffrin', for privacy.)

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'puttit')
at file:///Users/siffrin/Downloads/coursework/written%20stuff/bablog%20(capstone%20project)/index.js:17:25
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/siffrin/Downloads/coursework/written stuff/bablog (capstone project)/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Users/siffrin/Downloads/coursework/written stuff/bablog (capstone project)/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:149:13)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/siffrin/Downloads/coursework/written stuff/bablog (capstone project)/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:119:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/siffrin/Downloads/coursework/written stuff/bablog (capstone project)/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /Users/siffrin/Downloads/coursework/written stuff/bablog (capstone project)/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
at Function.process_params (/Users/siffrin/Downloads/coursework/written stuff/bablog (capstone project)/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
at next (/Users/siffrin/Downloads/coursework/written stuff/bablog (capstone project)/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
at /Users/siffrin/Downloads/coursework/written stuff/bablog (capstone project)/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:137:5
at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:211:14)

i have no idea WHY it's doing this. i've tried changing the names from "title" and i've tried looking it up, but from what i've found i don't think i can apply it in a way that works here
here's the code- i'm still a beginner at this, somewhat (though I did take JS in highschool lol) so please forgive me for any newbie mistakes. i WOULD like to make a for loop for the rest of the posts (and clean up those placeholders), but considering I can't get The Very First Post to work...
ejs
<head>
  <title>Bablog!:The Baba Blogging Platform!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div><img id="logo" src="/bablog.png" /></div>
  <div id="box">
    <div id="welcome">
      <p>Welcome to the <b>BABLOG!!!</b></p>
    </div>
    <% if (locals.ptit) {%>
    <div class="post">
        <h1><%= ptit[0] %></h1>
        <p><%= stuff[0] %></p>
    <form action="/delete" method="DELETE">
        <input type="submit" value="POST IS DONE" class="donebtn"/>

    </form></div>
    <% } %>
    <div id="place">
      <form action="/submit" method="POST">
        <label for="puttit"><input type="text" id="puttit" name="puttit" placeholder="title here"
            /></label>
        <br /><br />

        <label for="posty"><textarea
            name="posty"
            placeholder="Bablog your post!"
            rows="10"
            cols="30"
          ></textarea></label>
        
        <br /><br />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="post"><p>I'm a baba!</p></div>
    <div class="post"><p>I'm a baba!</p></div>
    <div class="post"><p>I'm a baba!</p></div>
    <div class="post"><p>I'm a baba!</p></div>
  </div>
</body>

js
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
var titles = [];
var posts = [];

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))


app.get("/", (res, req) => {
  req.render("blog.ejs");
});
app.post("/submit", (res, req) => {
    titles.push(req.body["puttit"]);
    posts.push(req.body["posty"]);
  req.render("blog.ejs", {
    ptit: titles,
    stuff: posts,
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Port: ${port}`);
});

css if you need that
* {
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
};
#logo {
}
#box {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 3fr;
    grid-template-rows: 2fr 3fr;
    row-gap: 5px;

}
#welcome {

}
.post {
    background-color: #d9396a;
    border: outset black double
}
.post > *{
    background-color: #d9396a;
    color: black

}
#place {
    grid-row: 2 / span 10;
}
input, textarea {
    background-color: #82261c;
    color: black
}
#place > * {
    border: outset white double;

}
.donebtn {
    float:right;
    background-color: white;
}```


For API methods, the correct parameter order is (req, res), not (res, req). Example from express.js docs:
admin.get('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(admin.mountpath) // /admin
  res.send('Admin Homepage')
})


if its that and only that why the checks rules BLINDING code won't BLINDING work i swear to stars-
edit: just did so. what the BLINDING STARS-
thank you so much... i should probably make it a point to remember its (req, res)... q, s, q, s,,, quxi stars. hm.

hahaha i assume it works now
